# Anaconda JupyterLab fredapi error with fred.get_series()

Tags: python

In Anaconda/JupyterLab I keep running into an error trying to pull data through the fredapi      package.fredapi 0.4.2 is correctly installed in my environment. Importing the package and assigning the API key works. It's only until I pull a series with get_series() function that I get an error.
I don't have this error in my notebook on DataCamp cloud in which I use the exact code.Any idea what is going on here? Thanks a lotI tried this:

```
import fredapi as Fred
my_api_key='some_number'
fred=Fred(api_key=my_api_key)
sp500=fred_get_series('SP500')
```

and got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15588\3735180914.py in <module>
      1 fred = Fred(api_key='48687714d90448d876bb115d06578128')
----> 2 fred.get_series('SP500')

~\anaconda3\envs\my_models\lib\site-packages\fredapi\fred.py in get_series(self, series_id, observation_start, observation_end, **kwargs)
    133             raise ValueError('No data exists for series id: ' + series_id)
    134         data = {}
--> 135         for child in root.getchildren():
    136             val = child.get('value')
    137             if val == self.nan_char:

AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren'` error occurs because the `getchildren()` method has been deprecated since Python 3.2 and was removed in Python 3.9. It seems that the FRED Python package you are using has not been updated to work with Python 3.9 or later.

Remove your currently installed fredapi, and re-install fredapi using pip:

```
conda uninstall fredapi

pip install fredapi
```